# After refreshing data in SwipeRefreshLayout the data disappears. why?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am using RecyclerView inside SwipeRefreshLayout.For the very first time, the data is loaded successfully but when I refresh the layout the data is gone. I used AsyncTask to load the data. After loading all the data then I notified the adapter that the data set has changed but still it is not working.

Comment: post your implementation codes here...

Comment: so what you can done code for this ?